# Seeing the disable state for a button

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

After a form is submitted I disable the submit button with

```
form$.find('button').prop('disable', true);
```

But I don't see the changed state with Chrome Dev tools for the button element. There's no attribute named 'disable' and nothing for 'properties' that I can see.

How can I see the disable state with Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Are you preventing the form submission, or is the page getting refreshed once it is submitted?

Comment: The page is not getting refreshed once it's submitted. Is that recommended, and is there a way to make the submit button do that ?

Comment: B default submit buttons inside `<form>` will submit the form once clicked. The reason I asked is because if the page is getting refreshed, you'll not be able to see the changes you made before refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `disabled` not disable.

```
form$.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what was keeping the button from being disabled. But still, how could I have seen the disabled state with Dev tools?

Comment: Just inspect that button you'll see that property.

Comment: Ok, here's a simple form: http://jsfiddle.net/yagzp457/ Can you see anywhere if the submit button is disabled or not?